# Why queue still waiting when send mail in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

i want send mail in queue and have not waiting when send mail
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#connections-vs-queues

i run command to create table `jobs`:

```
php artisan queue:table    
php artisan migrate
```

I create a job to send mail: `php artisan make:job SendEmailJob`
and edit code :

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Mail;
class SendEmailJob  implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $body;
    public $emailto;

    public function __construct($body,$email)
    {
        //
         $this->body=$body;
         $this->emailto=$email;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       $email=$this->emailto;
       Mail::send("body_email.confirm_order",['Body'=> $this->body], function($message) use ($email)
       {
           $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'),"Eye glasses");
           $message->subject("Confirm Email");
           $message->to($email);
       });  
    }
}
```

I call queue from controller:

```
use App\Jobs\SendEmailJob;

public function index()
{
     $Body="test";
     $email="daitb@vnitsolutions.com";     
     SendEmailJob::dispatch($Body,  $email);
     $calendars= AppointmentModel::GetAppointmentofDoctor($id,$datetime);      
     return view('frontend.appointment',["calendars"=>$calendars]);
}
```

add `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` to file `.env`
run command:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

If i run controller, process still waiting send mail finish and run other process.
i try change to:

```
SendEmailJob::dispatch($Body,  $email)->delay(now()->addMinutes(3));
```

It not delay,it still send mail after 5s.

Why queue still waiting when send mail in laravel?
I using win 32.

Comment: is your queue working i.e. have you ran `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: I run controller from website, it send mail ok. must i run php artisan queue:work?

Comment: how are you able to send mails, if your queue is not working?

Comment: I only call function index(), mail sent ok.

Comment: I using Dispatching Jobs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#connections-vs-queues

Comment: You need to set queue driver to database in your **.env** file and then run `php artisan queue:work`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Problem fixed by change `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` to `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` in  `.env` file